# autofac xml configuration

Tags: xml, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

I'm using autofac framework with xml configuration. I have a question, here is the situation. I have a class called ApplicationConfig that holds an array of objects thats implements an interface. And I have two methods Start and finish. The idea is call the start method at the beginning of the application and Finish at the end.

To set the objects I call SetConfigurations which has variable numbers of arguments.

Here is the code:

```cs
public class ApplicationConfig
{
    private IAppConfiguration[] configurators;

    public void SetConfigurations(params IAppConfiguration[] appConfigs)
    {
        this.configurators = appConfigs ?? new IAppConfiguration[0];
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        foreach (IAppConfiguration conf in this.configurators)
            conf.OnStart();
    }

    public void Finish()
    {
        foreach (IAppConfiguration conf in this.configurators)
            conf.OnFinish();
    }
}
```

xml

```xml
<component type="SPCore.ApplicationConfig, SPCore"
    instance-scope="single-instance">
</component>
```

I just wonder if I can via xml configure the components that will start at the begining of the app, in stead of `SetConfigurations`. I use `SetConfigurations` in app's code.

So i want something like this.

class constructor

```cs
public ApplicationConfig(params IAppConfiguration[] appConfigs)
{
    this.configurators = appConfigs;
}
```

xml

```xml
<component type="SPCore.ApplicationConfiguration.ConfigurationParamters, SPCore"
    instance-scope="single-instance">
</component>

<component type="SPCore.ApplicationConfig, SPCore" instance-scope="single-instance">
    <parameters>
        <parameter>--Any componet--</parameter>
        <parameter>--Any componet--</parameter>
        ....
        ....
        <parameter>--Any componet--</parameter>
    </parameters>
</component>
```

I don't know how to specify parameters for the constructor that are other components..

So, I want to be able to configure the app without compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autofac's XML configuration doesn't support this scenario.

The simplest way to achieve what you're after is to use `IStartable` (http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Startable) and `IDisposable` on the configuration objects, and not have an `ApplicationConfig` class at all. Autofac will call `Start()` and `Dispose()` automatically.

If you do need to have the `ApplicationConfig` class orchestrate the start/finish process, you can control which `IApplicationConfiguration` components are registered. By default, Autofac will inject *all* implementations of `IApplicationConfiguration` into the `appConfigs` constructor parameter, because it is an array and Autofac has special handling for array types. Just include `<component>` tags for each of the `IApplicationConfiguration`s you need, and exclude those you don't.

Hope this helps,

Nick